# How can I edit text in a specific xlsx column?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have duplicates of words/parts of sentences in texts saved in a specific column of an xlsx file, like:

"**Bakhtiar Mohammed AbdullaBakhtiar Mohammed Abdulla**A forensic analysis of Ms Borch's computer revealed that she had watched videos of the beheadings carried out by Mohammed Emwazi or Jihadi John, the British Isil fighter who tops Britain's kill list of terrorist targets in Syria." or "People greet refugees as they arrive at the main train station in Munich, Germany**People greet refugees as they arrive at the main train station in Munich**"

How can I remove the duplicated parts and replace them with a space?

My code so far:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

inp = pd.read_excel(r"location\file", header=0, converters={'Text':str}) # column containing the text is 'Text'
inp['Text'] = inp['Text'].str.replace(r'(?<!\S)((\w+(?:\s+\w+)+).*)\2(?=[A-Z]|\b)', r'\1', regex=True)
output = inp
output.to_excel(r"location\file", index_False)
```

Comment: Try `output = input['Text'].str.replace(r'(?<!\S)((\w+(?:\s+\w+)+).*)\2(?=[A-Z]|\b)', r'\1', regex=True)`. Also, please do not use built-ins as variable names.

Comment: no error messages here, but the quoted duplicate is still in there

Comment: Update the column, `input['Text'] = input['Text'].str.replace(r'(?<!\S)((\w+(?:\s+\w+)+).*)\2(?=[A-Z]|\b)', r'\1', regex=True)`

Comment: I edited the code above like suggested - but that still doesn't give me the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'([A-Z].+).*\1', r'\1 ', regex=True).str.strip()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Text
0  Bakhtiar Mohammed Abdulla A forensic analysis of Ms Borch's computer revealed that she had watched videos of the beheadings carried out by Mohammed Emwazi or Jihadi John, the Brit ain's kill list of terrorist targets in Syria
1                                                                                                                                                           People greet refugees as they arrive at the main train station in Munich
```

---

Input dataframe:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Text
0  Bakhtiar Mohammed AbdullaBakhtiar Mohammed AbdullaA forensic analysis of Ms Borch's computer revealed that she had watched videos of the beheadings carried out by Mohammed Emwazi or Jihadi John, the British Isil fighter who tops Britain's kill list of terrorist targets in Syria
1                                                                                                                               People greet refugees as they arrive at the main train station in Munich, GermanyPeople greet refugees as they arrive at the main train station in Munich
```